# UFW allows outgoing IPv6 even when default policy is to deny all outgoing

Tags: dns, firewall, ufw, ipv6, ping

I want to set a policy to deny outgoing connections by default.

1. DNS lookup should be allowed
2. Specific IPs should be allowed for outgoing connections

So I setup the following rules:

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out 53
sudo ufw allow out from any to 123.123.123.123
```

Check:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

Output:

```
Status: active
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 123.123.123.123            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 2] 53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[ 3] 53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
```

When I ping google.com
I expect DNS resolution to work but actual ping to fail. But the whole ping functionality is working. I notice that it uses IPv6 for the pining. Whereas with the firewall disabled, it uses IPv4.

```
PING google.com(fra15s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:815::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra15s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:815::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=3.90 ms
64 bytes from fra15s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:815::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=3.96 ms
64 bytes from fra15s12-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:815::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=3.94 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.903/3.936/3.965/0.025 ms
```

It appears that the firewall is successfully blocking IPv4, so the ping command tries using IPv6 and succeeds. The firewall is somehow not blocking IPv6.

Comment: ICMPv6 echo request/reply is permitted in UFW defaults.  You'd have to alter the UFW defaults.  `ufw` is not a *complete* view of wht it does or doesn't block.  To show *that* you'll have to search around the `ip6tables -L -n -v --line-numbers` output.  Let me do some minor research on this and get back to you with an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UFW firewall rules that you see in `ufw` commands are *not* the full set of rules that're actually implemented by UFW.  Underneath the hood, `iptables` / `netfilter` is what UFW manipulates and there are quite a few things that're *permitted* by the default UFW rules so that your internet, etc behaves proper..  Unfortunately to fix *those* rules, you have to edit some configuration files.

`/etc/ufw/before6.rules` is the file you're going to want to edit.  Find these two lines:

```
-A ufw6-before-output -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A ufw6-before-output -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

You can do one of two things: either change the `ACCEPT` to `DROP` here, or simply comment the two lines out to inherit default policies set by general policy (typically DROP I believe in your case?).  If you absolutely don't want to receive or send `PING`s via ICMP then you'll want to change these to `DROP`.

So the lines would look like this (and yes, add the comment I add in this block):

```
# Drop ICMPv6 outbound for echo replies and echo requests (PING)
-A ufw6-before-output -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -j DROP
-A ufw6-before-output -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-reply -j DROP
```

The rest of the ICMPv6 items in the list should be left alone - unlike ICMP in IPv4, IPv6 interoperability requires the sending/receiving of certain other types of packets to behave properly with IPv6 support in general, so IPv6 is much more dependent on its ICMP than IPv4 is.  So you should **leave the rest of the rules from UFW alone**.

Then you should run `sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable && sudo ufw reload` just to make sure that UFW actually updates its rules from the altered definitions.

---

Note that if your intent is to *disable* IPv6 support, then you need to do some network-configuration-level changes to actually get stuff to behave proper and disable IPv6 support by default.  That way, even if DNS resolves to IPv6 records, the system doesn't support IPv6 and won't attempt to use it.  (This being said, `ufw` is designed to be **uncomplicated** and disabling IPv6 outright is a lot harder than you think - also beyond the scope of this question)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I guess I will let the config be as is since though ping works, outgoing TCP connections are blocked by default which was my main intention. Thank you very much.